# Why is login screen different after waking from suspend?

Tags: 17.04, login-screen, display-manager

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. My login screen suddenly looks different now.

[image: Here's a photo of said screen]

Excuse the smudges. The laptop is worn out.

As you can see, it now has an on-screen keyboard and a white window prompt for the password. Prior to this, I may have pressed some specific combination of keys, maybe something like Ctrl+Alt+Shift I can't remember, which then launched an on-screen keyboard. The login screen has changed as shown everytime pc resumes from suspend since then.

I haven't installed anything except for python3, idle3, pyqt4 and pyqt5 packages. No new desktop environments.

I just want the default Unity login screen back.

**UPDATE:** I have disabled "Onboard" appearance. Resume screen problem still persists.

**UPDATE:** It looks like I have accidentally changed the so-called display manager from lightdm to something else. But actually I didn't, as proven in this file:

[image]

I've tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` but it doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Comment: This looks like the resume screen for Ubuntu Mate

Comment: Still waiting for insights.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu mate

Comment: No. It's Unity 7.5.0

Comment: What do you mean Unity, what version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Ubuntu Unity? Canonical's default graphical shell for Ubuntu Gnome since Ubuntu 10? As I mentioned Ubuntu version is 17.04.

Comment: Point is there's no way it is actually MATE that I have installed. It's just the one you get by default when you download the desktop image from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/

Comment: Two thoughts. First of all, this definitely looks like a lightdm login screen (see [here](https://tinyurl.com/y9qzvemb)), but one that people only see b/c of a bug related to gnome-screensaver. Try uninstalling it (`sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver`).

Comment: Gnome desktop packages have been known to interfere with lightdm, so your problem could be due to some other gde/unity conflict. Since dpkg-reconfigure didn't work you could also try completely removing (purging) lightdm and reinstalling it. You might want to also take a look at config files, see [here](https://tinyurl.com/y9qzvemb)

Comment: One more thing, check out this article's "[Change Login Greeter](http://support.system76.com/articles/desktop-environment/#change-login-greeter)" section for more detailed instructions about the lines in the .conf to change